# Where is the missing ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average, word-problem, ratio

On a day at the Fruits Exchange, an apple can be exchanged for 2 bananas, and a banana exchanged for 2 oranges. The market is perfectly efficient, so an apple can be traded for 4 oranges.

On another day at the Fruits Exchange, there are some shortages of apples and bananas, so the exchange rate of apples to bananas rises to 1 apple for 3 bananas, and 1 banana for 3 oranges.

The average exchange rate over the two days for apples to bananas is $\frac{(1:2 + 1:3)}{2} = 1:2.5$,

And the average exchange rate over the two days for bananas to oranges is the same.

Then the average exchange rate for apples to oranges should be $1:2.5^2 = 1:6.25$

However, if you exchanged an apple on each of the two days, you would have received $4+9=13$ oranges, hence setting the average exchange rate to $2:13=1:6.5$.

Where did the missing 0.25 ratio go ?

Comment: Seems to be Simpsons paradox.

Comment: @Peter I don't think that's that, even if it was only for one exchange rate (apples to bananas) we'd get a similar contradiction. I think the problem is just that they are taking the arithmetic mean of two ratios and expecting that it equals the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of the two quantities.

Comment: @amWhy I just re-added the tags you removed because I think it was an edit clash (we edited at about the same time). If you deliberately removed them because you think they are inappropriate then I apologize.

Comment: No problem, Snaw. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the situation. In store A a toothbrush costs $\$10$, and in store B it costs $\$20$. If I buy one toothbrush at each store, how much did I pay on average? $\$15$.

But in store A a single dollar gets me $\frac{1}{10}$ of a toothbrush, and in store B a single dollar gets me $\frac{1}{20}$ of a toothbrush. So a single dollar seemingly gets me an average of $\frac{\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{20}}{2}$ toothbrushes which equals $\frac{3}{40}$, which is different from $\frac{1}{15}$.

You can't take the average of ratios (rates) then take the reciprocal of that and expect to get the average of the quantities themselves. This will give false results. That is, $\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}{2}}$ does not in general equal $\frac{a+b}{2}$. The first quantity is called the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of $a$ and $b$ and the second quantity is called the arithmetic mean of $a$ and $b$, and [they are not in general equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Relationship_with_other_means).

For another example, imagine a car which passes 1 km between 8am and 9am, and then on a slower road it passes 1 km between 9am and 11am. It passed 2 km in 3 hours so its average speed was $\frac{2}{3}$ km/h. On the other hand averaging its two individual speeds on the two separate roads we get $\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}}{2}=\frac{3}{4}$, which is wrong. The reason it is wrong is that the car spent more time on the second road. This same intuition is the reason for why the arithmetic and harmonic means don't in general equal one another.

Specifically for your question, your second calculation is the correct one since instead of averaging the exchange ratios it considered the amount of oranges paid per apple, on the first day we get $4$ oranges per apple, and on the second day we get $9$ oranges per apple, and so on average we get $\frac{9+4}{2}=6.5$ oranges per apple. The first calculation is incorrect for the same reason taking the average speed of the cars in the two separate roads is incorrect.

Comment: wow I didn't know there were different kinds of averages

Comment: @seok I added a second example with some intuition for why the arithmetic mean and harmonic mean should not in general agree with one another.

Comment: yes this seems obvious now!

Comment: in which situations would harmonic means be useful ?

Comment: @seok Imagine the same car where we are instead given only its speeds on the two separate roads. In the first road we were given that its speed was $1$ and in the second road its speed was $\frac{1}{2}$. The harmonic mean of $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ is $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{2}{1+2}=\frac{2}{3}$. So if we are given the speeds and we want to calculate the average speed then the harmonic mean is the right way to do this.